# How to Serialize with field from reverse related model - Django rest framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have an api that retrieves all items related to a project through a manytomany model with an extra order field. I am now trying to serialize the items with the order value on it.

One solution would be to serialize the through model, but that gives a result like this:

```
{
    "order": 1,
    "item": {
        "id": 3031,
        "name": "Miami"
    }
},
```

I would like to serialize the item instead and get an output like so:

```
{
    "order": 1,
    "id": 3031,
    "name": "Miami"
}
```

I can't add the order as an Attribute to the item model, as it's a manytomany field. Or I guess I could but would have to take the first object of a list, which is not a solution I think is very clean and would probably add a separate database call.

All the items are fetch like so:

```
ProjectItem.objects.filter(project_id=self.kwargs['project_pk']).select_related('item')
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a through model, then you should serialize it and use the `source` extra argument to "flatten" the representation.

For example, for `name`, it would be

```
name = serializers.CharField(source='item.name')
```

You probably will have to write the serializer create / update methods to make this work for writable.

Comment: Good idea. I went with a bit different method as you can see in my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you for some reason don't want to go through the through model like @Linovia suggests, then you can prefetch the through model and use a RelatedField with an overwritten to_representation.

This is what I did:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

Item.objects.filter(projectitem_set__project_id=self.kwargs['project_pk'])
    .prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('projectitem_set', queryset=ProjectItem.objects.filter(project_id=self.kwargs['project_pk']), to_attr='order'))
```

Then added this to the ItemSerializer (don't add many=True):

```
order = ProjectItemSerializer(read_only=True)
```

And overwrite the to_representation in the ProjectItemSerializer:

```
class ProjectItemSerializer(serializers.RelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return value[0].order
```

value[0] gets the first object of the prefetched values